# Azure apimanagement with subscriptions on a subset of operations, is it possible?

Tags: azure-api-management

Setting up an API with Azure API management. We've created 2 products, one that requires subscription and one that don't. We did this as vi have a single API where we want some of the operations to required subscription and others where we don't. Is this possible in a single API or do we need to create two APIs? The issue with 2 APIs is that any prefix ala "/api" needs to be different, and we want it to look like a single API

Comment: Make subscription not required and write a policy expression that checks for the subscription key header , also there are many restriction policies that you may use like JWT authentication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, unfortunately.

As stated in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions) subscriptions only apply to Products and individual APIs.

Se this [UserVoice suggestion](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/17283983-api-operation-visibility) where "Operation Visibility" is suggested.

Greetings from Denmark ;-)

/rasmus

Comment: It can be also user specific subscription if that helps somehow.